# get sheets name list from google drive using oauth2 token react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, oauth, google-drive-api

I want to get all `sheet names` of the connected google account in my application. For this, I created oauth2 and got the client ID and enabled Google Drive API for accessing the Sheets in Google Cloud Console. On Clicking the button in my app, I opened the `Google SignIn Panel` for selecting Account. On selecting the Account, I get the profile Details. Now I want to get all the sheet names of the account. I searched a lot. But can't find any solutions. Please Help me with some solutions. I need to list out the sheet names of the connected google account

Here's the Code for Authorization:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const googleClientID = 'xxxsxxxx-xxxxxxdfdfdxxxxxx2.apps.googleusercontent.com'

    const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
        console.log("googleSuccess")
        console.log(res)
    }

    const googleError = (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert('Google Sign In was unsuccessful. Try again later');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        function start() {
            gapi.client.init({
                clientId: googleClientID,
                scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'profile'],
            });
        }

        gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
    }, []);

    return (
        <GoogleLogin
            clientId={googleClientID}
            render={(renderProps) => (
                <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", width: "400px" }}
                    fullWidth onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                    disabled={renderProps.disabled} startIcon={<Icon />} variant="contained">
                    Add Subscription by Google Sign In
                </Button>
            )}
            onSuccess={googleSuccess}
            onFailure={googleError}
            cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
        />
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: In this case why don't you try using the Sheets API to retrieve that information? Drive API doesn't seem to have any method to retrieve the information within a Google Sheet. Sheets API does retrieve the Sheet title when you use the [`spreadsheets.get` method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets)

Comment: @Gabriel Carballo, May I know how to use that in here. Do you have any sample code..